# How to change columnDefs in angular-ui-grid after instantiation?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angular-ui-grid and am having problems changing the columns.

```
TypeError: self.options.columnDefs.forEach is not a function
```

Code is as follows:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.columns1 = [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}];
        $scope.columns2 = [{field: 'new_name', displayName: 'New Name'}, {field:'new_age', displayName:'New Age'},{field:'pin', displayName:'Pin'}];
        $scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns1;
        $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                         {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                         {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                         {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                         {name: "Enos", age: 34}];  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
                init: function (gridCtrl, gridScope) {
                    gridScope.$on('ngGridEventData', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            angular.forEach(gridScope.columns, function (col) {
                                gridCtrl.resizeOnData(col);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                },    
    paginationPageSize: 5,
    data: {'name':'Apple','age': 5 },
    columnDefs: 'columnsSelected'
  }; 

        $scope.update_columns = function($event) { 

          $scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns2;

          $scope.myData = [{new_name: "Moroni", new_age: 50, pin: 123},
           {new_name: "Tiancum", new_age: 43, pin: 345},
           {new_name: "Jacob", new_age: 27, pin: 567},
           {new_name: "Nephi", new_age: 29, pin: 789},
           {new_name: "Enos", new_age: 34, pin: 012}
          ];
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is `self.options.columnDefs.forEach` in the code?

Comment: Updated OP, please check. It looks like it is an ng-grid specific thing?

Comment: I don't see `$timeout` anywhere in the dependencies list of the controller

Comment: When I comment out the lines with the forEach, I still get that error, which leads me to think there is something else going on.

Comment: and why `columnDefs: 'columnsSelected'` ? shouldn't it be `columnDefs: $scope.columnsSelected` ? (BTW, you only changing the reference when you do `$scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns2;` after declaring the grid options, it might cause an unexpected behaviour later so watch out

Comment: Thats what I had before, didn't work, saw some posting somewhere that having it with the string quotes makes it look for the scope variable with the name. Both ways did not work, which is why I am posting my question.